# Vagrant won't run

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have installed Vagrant and VirtualBox on my 64 bit Windows machine. When I try to run a 'vagrant up' I et the following message:

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["modifyvm", "01fd6095-edae-4c33-93c8-3c9d10ab4430",
>   "--name", "xxx_1397481035300_70240"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not rename the directory
>   'D:\VirtualBox VMs \packer-virtualbox-iso_1397480994399_38288' to
>   'D:\VirtualBox VMs\xxx_1397481035300_70240'
>   to save the  settings file (VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) VBoxManage.exe:
>   error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component SessionMachi ne,
>   interface IMachine, callee IUnknown VBoxManage.exe: error: Context:
>   "SaveSettings()" at line 2716 of file VBoxManage ModifyVM.cpp

I have tried re-installing both programs to no avail.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I had my VirtualBox VMs folder misspelled. I renames it and it works now.